# How to alternate between file input and terminal input in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a `bash` script that reads from a file. After reading from the file, I would like to prompt the user for input, and read it from the terminal.

Here's a excerpt of my code:

```
while IFS=',' read -r a b c
do
    #a, b, c are read in from file
    data1=$a
    data2=$b
    data3=$c

    #later in the loop
    #answer should be read in from the terminal
    echo "Enter your answer to continue:"
    read answer

done
```

However, currently I think the script thinks I am trying to read in `answer` from the same input file as `a`, `b`, and `c`. How do I alternate between file and terminal input?

Comment: stdin is not command-line input; edited to refer to "terminal input".

Comment: ("command-line input" implies that the parameters were actually put on your program's command line, as in, `./yourprogram "first answer" "second answer" "third answer"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your stdin has been redirected from a file (that is, you were invoked with `./yourscript <file`), then use `/dev/tty` to read from the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3</dev/tty || {
  echo "Unable to open TTY; this program needs to read from the user" >&2
  exit 1
}

while IFS= read -r line; do # iterate over lines from stdin
  if [[ $line = Q ]]; then
    echo "Getting input from the user to process $line" >&2
    read -r answer <&3 # read input from descriptor opened to /dev/tty earlier
  else
    echo "Processing $line internally"
  fi
done
```

If you want to skip the `exec 3</dev/tty` up by the top (opening `/dev/tty` just once at the beginning of your script, allowing reads from the TTY to later be done with `<&3`), then you could instead write:

```
read -r answer </dev/tty
```

...to open it every time you want to perform a read from the terminal. However, you'd want to be sure to have error-handling for the case where it fails on these occasions within your loop (for instance, if this code is running from a cron job, a `ssh` invocation with a command passed as an argument and no `-t`, or a similar situation where there *is* no TTY).

---

Alternately, consider opening your file on a descriptor other than stdin -- here, we use file descriptor #3 for file input, and assume invocation as `./yourscript file` (with stdin pointing to the terminal):

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1

while IFS= read -r line <&3; do # reading file contents from FD 3
  if [[ $line = Q ]]; then
    echo "Getting input from the user to process $line" >&2
    read -r answer # reading user input by default from FD 0
  else
    echo "Processing $line internally" >&2
  fi
done 3<"$filename" # opening the file on FD 3
```

Comment: Always insightful, and always a few nuggets to add to the bash toolbox.